# What was the first use/cite of "Watt's law"?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, history, power

Yesterday I saw a reference to Watt's law being used for the power formula P = V I.

It's been over 40 years since I learned my basic electrical engineering fundamentals and this is the first time that I recall seeing the phrase Watt's law used to represent this formula.

Doing some searching around on the web I haven't found where this term first showed up but have seen plenty of people on both sides of the flag claiming this is a proper law and others saying not.

Have done a fair bit of reading on Watt and his accomplishments in steam and mechanical power but don't recall that he ever did anything with electricity.

While the watt has since become a standardized unit of work (joules per second), I don't recall reading anything about Watt himself showing that volts times amperes equals power.

So, really interested in finding when/where this usage originated.

Comment: This might be more apt for the History of Science and Mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I will post it over there as well.

Comment: +1 for correct capitalization of watt (the unit) and Watt (the engineer/scientist).